# Solving $x^p+ax^q+b=0$ with $x,a,b$ integer and $p-q>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

Help solving $x^p+ax^q+b=0$, where $p,q,x \geq 0$ and $a,b \in\mathbb{Z}$.

I am well aware of the complexity of this equation. However, I am mostly interested in the following particular case: Given that $x$ is a non-negative integer, if $p-q>1$, can't I derive logically that $x=b=0$?

Comment: $a = 0$, $b = -n^p$, $x = n$.

Comment: $2^{17}+19\times2^{11}+b=0$, where $b=-2^{17}-19\times2^{11}$.

Comment: Thank you guys. Here is the reason why I was thinking that $x=b=0$. When we have a $F(x)=0$ of degree $p$, the coefficient of the term $p-1$, isn't it the sum of all the solutions $x_{i}$ with $i=1,2,....,p$? If they are all non-negative, how can we have any non-trivial roots? Where did I go wrong? Please explain.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, RghtHndSd, thank you.

Comment: The solutions can't *all* be positive --- but they can't all be negative, either. But they can be some of each.

Comment: Why not? In the hypothesis, $x$ is positive.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, by the way the equation $x^{17}+19x^{11}-2^{17}-19x2^{11}=0$ has only one rational root. The other 16 are all Gaussian.

Comment: As you say, the sum of the roots is zero, so they can't all be positive, and they can't all be negative. I don't know what you mean by "Gaussian".

Comment: Complex numbers

Comment: I am not arguing that you are wrong, I am just trying to understand.

Comment: OK, so it's not clear to me just what it is that you don't understand. But maybe it would be good to post a new question to zero in on the exact point(s) where you need further explanation, rather than trying to accomplish anything in these comments.

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: I just can't wrap my mind around the fact that in the hypothesis it's assumed that all the solutions are non-negative and we noted the term that is supposed to be the sum of those solutions in the polynomial equation is zero, but yet we do have a non-trivial solution?

Comment: I read the hypothesis as assuming that there is at least one non-negative solution $x$. If you take the hypothesis as assuming every solution is non-negative (implying that every solution is real), then every solution is zero, and $a$ and $b$ are both zero, and your polynomial is just $x^p$.

Comment: Why does $a$ have to be equal to zero? I was thinking $$x^{p-q}=-a$$ where $(-a)$ is a positive integer to the power $p-q$.

Comment: Well, note that (for example) the equation $x^2=9$ has a solution that isn't a non-negative integer. So does the equation $x^3=8$, if you permit non-real solutions. If *every* solution is real and non-negative, then every solution is zero, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot prove that $x=b=0$.

Factoring your original equation, and noting that $p-q>1$, we have
$$
  x^q\left(x^{p-q}+a\right) = -b,
$$
where both factors on the left-hand side are integers. This equation evidently has no solutions with $a,b>0$ (because $x>0$), but it has many possible solutions otherwise.